# How to multiple channel entries in single generated pdf

Tags: shine-pdf

As per We know , shine pdf only one time parsing so that  we could not embed / stash  other channel data entries in single pdf generate.

it means , how can we generate multiple channel data without any relation between channel in single shine pdf generate?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it through embeds sort of like this:

```
{embed='inc/generatePDF' pdfContent='
    {exp:channel:entries channel="foo"}
        {title}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="bar"}
        {title}
    {/exp:channel:entries}'}
```

And then in your inc/generatePDF file you enable php and do something like this:

```
 <? $someVar = '{embed:pdfContent}'; ?>

 {exp:shine_pdf:make}
    <? echo $someVar; ?>
 {/exp:shine_pdf:make}
```